# python 3.4 - django 1.11

Tags: python, mysql, django, pymysql

I am new to django, after many tries to find a pip install package for linking mysql to django, I have been able to successfully install it using pip3 install pymysql. Now this hasn't been given up on django documentation 1.11. Django documentation only mention of MySQL DB API Drivers are
1. MySQLdb 
2. mysqlclient
3. MySQL Connector/Python

Now after a long hardwork in just figuring out how to properly install a db driver. without any error for my win 10.
I want to know will pymsql will work successfully for my setup?

Comment: mysqldb just need you to run `pip3 install mysqldb` and [mysqlclient](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/). If you are still new then I prefer you should try with default module shown in django documentation because you can get your answers from their for further steps and problem.

Comment: pip3 install mysql and mysqlclient have tried a lot but it doesn't seems to work, it keeps giving errors. And I have a project where I do need to use mysqldb. SQLite(default) won't work.

Comment: for pip3 install mysqlclient
warning: no files found matching 'GPL-2.0'
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'my_config.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

Comment: And for pip3 install mysqldb..... Collecting mysqldb
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqldb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysqldb

Comment: install vc_redist for your pc

Comment: You should talk to the good folks at Django if you have questions about how their docs or how their application can be used.

Comment: @Gahan done that also. above errors that i have mentioned are the errors after installing and updating vc redist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqlclient` should work fine if you are planning to use MySql for your project. You can try downloading the .whl file for your windows and python configuration from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)

Since you are using python3.4 download the mysqlclient‑1.3.10‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl file. Once you do that. Install that .whl file with command.

```
pip install /path/to/your/.whl file/some-package.whl
```

Then you can continue with django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/).